# Next JS компилит очень много модулей

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, nextjs

Это нормально что при изменении страницы Next JS компилит 9000 модулей?

```
wait  - compiling /dashboard-company...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 1213 ms (9085 modules)
```